# SolrCloud shard splitting and host count

Tags: solr, amazon-ec2, solrcloud

I currently have a SolrCloud with 3 shards + replicas, it is holding 130M documents and the r3.large hosts are running out of memory.  As it's on 4.2 there is no shard splitting, I will have to reindex to a 4.3+ version.

If I had that feature would I need to split each shard into 2 subshards resulting in a total of 6 subshards, in order to keep all shards relatively equal?

And since host memory is the problem I'd be migrating subshards to new hosts.  So it seems I'd be going from 6 hosts to 12. Are these assumptions correct or is there a way to avoid doubling my host count?

Comment: I'd rather see what is causing the out of memory exception before going into splitting into sub-shards... you could only need to optimize the JVM parameters... or you could be cashing more that what you need... or you could be having a non-optimised query, or indexing more than what you should do.... sometimes scaling hardware is not always the solution.

Comment: @Emad    Is there a way to reduce the number of docs SOLR is cacheing?  That would help.  The error is always this one `code` SEVERE: null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocTermOrds.uninvert(DocTermOrds.java:279)
`code`

Comment: you can set the size property in cashing, start here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching